# how do you set a field to be not_analyized on a field that contains spaces?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a 'grade' field in an Elasticsearch index that contains text and numbers. I have set the field mapping to be 'not_analyized' but I can't search for grade ==== 'Year 1'.

I have read the [finding exact values](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_finding_exact_values.html) section of the docs but it doesn't seem to work for me.

Create the index.

```
curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/my_test_index
```

Create the mapping template.

```
curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/_template/my_test_index_mapping -d '
{
  "template" : "my_test_index",
  "mappings" : {
    "my_type": {
      "properties": {       
        "grade": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        }
      }      
    }
  }
}
'
```

Create some documents.

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/my_test_index/my_type/1' -d '{
  "title" : "some title",
  "grade" : "Year 1"
}'

curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/my_test_index/my_type/3' -d '{
  "title" : "some title",
  "grade" : "preschool"
}'
```

Query for "Year 1" returns 0 results.

```
curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/my_test_index/_search -d '{ 
    "query": { 
        "filtered" : { 
            "filter" : { 
                "term": { 
                    "grade": "Year 1"
                } 
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

Query for 'preschool' returns 1 result.

```
curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/my_test_index/_search -d '{ 
    "query": { 
        "filtered" : { 
            "filter" : { 
                "term": { 
                    "grade": "preschool"
                } 
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

Checking the mapping and the 'grade' field does not show 'not_analyzed'.

```
curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/my_test_index/_mapping

{
  "my_test_index" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "my_type" : {
        "properties" : {
          "grade" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "title" : {
            "type" : "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template will only impact newly created indices.

Re-Created the index after the template has been created.

Alternatively, specify the mappings while creating the index, instead of relying on templates to a single index.

Comment: I just worked that out about 5 seconds before you posted. Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the field to be analysed you can specify "index" : "not_analyzed" in the mapping. You'll then be able to search for exact matches as desired.

See: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-core-types.html#string

In your case,Please try to Re-create your mapping.

Comment: This question has already been answered so I'm not sure why you posted this. The problem was that the mapping template was applied before the index creation.